# Call a Javascript function multiple times with the same HTML ID

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with calling an `onclick` function multiple times. The problem is that I am using the same ID but I want to be able to reuse the function again for the second call. Here's what I have so far:

```
<p onclick='myfunction()'> Click this text for input box  below </p>
<b id='myThing'>input box appears .. ta daa</b>
<p onclick='myfunction()'> Click this new text for input box below </p>
<div id='myThing'> but no input box appears here, the line above must turn this text into a  textbox, but it doesn't because of similar id, how do i fix the id problem without defining a new id over and over?</div>
<script>
  function myfunction(){
    document.getElementById("myThing").innerHTML='<input type="text"/>';
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way to convert the ID into a Javascript variable? How do I make the  part create an input box?

Comment: what do you mean by javascript variable. What you are really trying to do

Comment: Beware not to give the same ID to two elements. Was it just an error in preparing the question ?

Comment: Different elements shouldn't have the same ID. That's why the second call doesn't work... `document.getElementById("myThing")` will find the first one and stop there...

Comment: Yes, i am trying to use something like the id to call on that javascript function, like if i could call it with some variable "x" instead of an id, because for an id i have to use different ids, this is the problem i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do this :

```
<p onclick='myfunction("myThing")'> Click this new text for input box below </p>
<script>
function myfunction(id){
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<input type="text"/>';
 }
 </script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/cEJsW/)

Note that you may also make the whole thing simpler : simply not use any id but let the function find the next element :

```
<p onclick='myfunction(this)'> Click this text for input box  below </p>
<b>input box appears .. ta daa</b>
<p onclick='myfunction(this)'> Click this new text for input box below </p>
<div> but no input box appears here, the line above must turn this text into a  textbox, but it doesn't because of similar id, how do i fix the id problem without defining a new id over and over?</div>

​<script>
function myfunction(element){
    do {
        element = element.nextSibling;
    } while (element && element.nodeType != 1);
    element.innerHTML='<input type="text"/>';
 }
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nCuFz/)

Comment: Yes yes yes, thank you thank you, use 'this' thing. That's what I was trying to do. Sorry I can't upvote you, says i need 15 reputation points. New to javascript here.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't need to use an ID to get the div.

```
function myfunction(){
 this.nextSibling.innerHTML='<input type="text"/>';
 }
```

Comment: You didn't test it on OP's code, right ? See my answer for correct version.

Comment: <p onclick='myfunction(this)'> Click this text for input box  below </p>
        <b id='myThing'>input box appears .. ta daa</b>
      <p onclick='myfunction(this)'> Click this new text for input box below </p>

     <div id='myThing'> but no input box appears here, the line above must turn this text into a  textbox, but it doesn't because of similar id, how do i fix the id problem without defining a new id over and over?</div>
    <script>
function myfunction(obj){
 obj.nextSibling.innerHTML='<input type="text"/>';
 }
     </script>